# iCloud storage always full

Tags: icloud

I am clearly missing some with iCloud storage, every few weeks I get an email saying my storage is nearly full and I only have a couple of hundred MB left. So I am always deleting my back up and letting it back up overnight. When I back it up it's only about 3GB. Why is it consistently over the weeks always full? I have no apps being backed up to it either, they're all off. So how do I stop this and what is causing it?

Here is an example of what I mean. It backed up yesterday. I have all the apps off and it wants to back up another 192MB. I haven't sent s load of images in iMessage or anything like this in the last day so I don't know where the data is coming from. I don't take many photos anyway so it's not photos. Unless it has anything to do with Apple Watch? I can't see or find anything about activity app being backed up the cloud, but that's the only thing left I can think of

[image]

Comment: Does any of your iMessage history contain a large number of photos or videos? Those may be included in the information stored in iCloud from your phone and may be separate from your Photo Library maintained in iCloud.

Comment: @RobPaller I don't have a lot I don't think. But reading this I kinda thought that it didn't matter anyway http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/234825/does-imessage-take-up-icloud-storage-space?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Unless it has anything to do with Apple Watch? I can't see or find
> anything about activity app being backed up the cloud, but that's the
> only thing left I can think of

The extra backup space is definitely from the watch.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204518

> Here's what your Apple Watch backup will include:
>
> App-specific data (for built-in apps) and settings (for built-in and third-party apps), such as Maps, distance, and units
>
> General system settings, such as your watch face, known Wi-Fi
> networks, brightness, sound, and haptic settings
>
> **Health and Fitness data, such as history, achievements, Workout and Activity calibration data from your Apple Watch, and user-entered data
> (To back up Health and Fitness data, you need to use iCloud or an
> encrypted iTunes backup.)**
>
> Language
>
> Settings for Mail, Calendar, Stocks, and Weather
>
> Time Zone

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings > General > Storage & iCloud Usage. Under the iCloud section, tap Manage Storage. This will show you everything that is using space in your iCloud account. If you see something you do not want backing up to iCloud, then disable and delete it here. iCloud Photo Library may be the culprit.

On the bottom of this page you can also select Change Storage Plan to purchase additional storage; in the US, the $0.99/month plan gives you 50 GB, which should be plenty for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I have no apps set to back up which is my point. The next scheduled back up as I deleted my latest one is for 2.9GB. But in a few weeks it will say I'm out of space.

Comment: Did you check the setting given?  It will tell you exactly what is using your space.  Photo's perhaps?